# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'NET_NAME'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

python 3.7
A task. Add a new column in the received date frame based on two conditions:
if the value in the NET_NAME column is equal to one of the list and the value in the ECELL_TYPE column is LTE, then assign the value to the SHARING column from the ENODEB_NAME column.

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

from time import gmtime, strftime
WCOUNT=strftime("%V", gmtime())
WCOUNT = int(WCOUNT)
WCOUNT_last = int(WCOUNT)-1
os.environ['NLS_LANG'] = 'Russian.AL32UTF8'

cell_file_list=pd.read_excel('cdt_config.xlsx',sheet_name ='cdt_config',index_col='para_name')
filial_name_list=pd.read_excel('FILIAL_NAME.xlsx')
gcell_file_name1=cell_file_list.para_value.loc['ucell_file_name']
ecell_file_name=cell_file_list.para_value.loc['ecell_file_name']
cols_simple=['RECDATE','REGION_PHOENIX_NAME','NET_NAME','CELL_NAME_IN_BSC','ENODEB_NAME','ECELL_TYPE','NRI_ADDRESS', 'NRI_BS_NUMBER','NRI_SITEID','STOPTIME',  ]
cols_export=['GSM', 'UMTS', 'LTE', 'TOTAL', 'NWEEK', 'SHARING' ]
ecell_df=df = pd.read_csv(ecell_file_name, sep=",",encoding='cp1251',
                dtype={'NRI_SITEID': str})

ecell_df=ecell_df.rename(columns={"RECDATE.DATE": "RECDATE"})
ecell_df=ecell_df.rename(columns={"ECELL_MNEMONIC": "CELL_NAME_IN_BSC"})

#replace ","
ecell_df.STOPTIME=pd.to_numeric(ecell_df.STOPTIME.replace(',', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')/3600
ecell_df=ecell_df[cols_simple]
#pivot ecell table
ecell_sum_df=pd.pivot_table(ecell_df,values='STOPTIME',index=['RECDATE','NRI_SITEID','REGION_PHOENIX_NAME','NET_NAME','ENODEB_NAME','ECELL_TYPE'],aggfunc='sum')
ecell_sum_df=ecell_sum_df.fillna(0)
#create a empty column with the same index as the pivot table.
ecell_export_df= pd.DataFrame(index=ecell_sum_df.index.copy())
ecell_export_df=ecell_export_df.assign(LTE=0)
ecell_export_df.LTE=ecell_sum_df.STOPTIME
ecell_export_df['SHARING'] = 0
ecell_export_df.SHARING.replace(ecell_export_df.NET_NAME in filial_name_list, ENODEB_NAME,inplace=True)
print(ecell_export_df)
#print (ecell_export_df)
del ecell_df
del ecell_sum_df

export_df=pd.concat([ecell_export_df],join='outer',axis=1)
export_df=export_df.fillna(0)
export_df['TOTAL'] = export_df.sum(axis=1)
export_df['NWEEK'] = WCOUNT_last

del ecell_export_df
#################################################
```

Below is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/ReportCDT/CDT 4G_power pivot.py", line 43, in <module>
ecell_export_df.SHARING.replace(ecell_sum_df.NET_NAME in filial_name_list, ENODEB_NAME,inplace=True)
File "C:\Users\vavrumyantsev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
eturn object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'NET_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback contains: *DataFrame object has no attribute NET_NAME*,
meaning actually that this *DataFrame* has no **column** of this name.

This message pertains to *ecell_sum_df.NET_NAME* (also contained in
the traceback), so let's look how you created this DataFrame (slightly
reformatted for readablity):

```
ecell_sum_df=pd.pivot_table(ecell_df, values='STOPTIME',\
    index=['RECDATE', 'NRI_SITEID', 'REGION_PHOENIX_NAME', 'NET_NAME',
    'ENODEB_NAME', 'ECELL_TYPE'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Note that *NET_NAME* is a part of the *index* list, so in the DataFrame
created it is a part of the **MultiIndex**, not an "ordinary" column.
So *Python* is right displaying this message.

Maybe you should move this level of the MultiIndex to a "normal" column?

Comment: I don’t quite understand how to do this? Looking at pivot table results like regular columns?

Comment: You should call *reset_index* passing the correct index level (at which this column occurs).
Search also the Web for *pandas drop index level*, you will find numerous examples.